# Receiver sensitivity estimation

Tags: rf, sensitivity

Is it possible to roughly estimate the sensitivity of a receiver in an an echoic chamber where there is no input signal supplied but the chamber just has noise.

Given the receiver sensitivity equation having SNR component in it. Would like to if there is any rough estimation that can be made with just noise.

Comment: You need a known source to provide a known power density (uW per cm^2, for instance) at the antenna to measure sensitivity.  Note that this is an exquisitely hard measurement to make accurately, particularly if you are going to compare that measurement to a predict.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it possible to roughly estimate the sensitivity of a receiver in an
> an echoic chamber where there is no input signal supplied but the
> chamber just has noise.*

Unfortunately not. The receiver chain and its antenna also produce self-noise due to the temperature at which they are at so, you have no steady reference point.

You do not know if the noise on the receiver output is due to true input noise from the chamber (multiplied by receiver gain) or, whether it's due to the internal noise generated by the receiver.